# Is there a synonym for fail better?

Tags: synonyms

This is a passage from Samuel Beckett’s play Worstword Ho, 1983: “...All of old. Nothing else ever. Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try again. Fail again. Fail better ...” Since I first read this passage, I’d always interpreted “fail better” to mean “to fail in way that is less of a failure.” But recently I read that by “fail better,” Beckett meant “to fail in a way that is even more of a failure,” and that this was Beckett’s true literary goal. Is there a verb that conveys the second interpretation?

Comment: Fail miserably, utterly fail?

Comment: Those would be the result, but how to get the goal of failure in there...

Comment: I think if there were a synonym that conveyed the meaning it would ruin the poetic and rhetorical effect. But this is the realms of literary criticism. So, lest I post a comment that is *entirely* off-topic, I will suggest that no there isn't a synonym, because the whole of the passage is needed in order for the meaning of that final verb and adverb to be fully understandable.

Comment: Please consider that good writers use the best of their language. Looking for "better" ways to say something like this is not "better". Unless this whole question is an attempt to "fail better"...?

Comment: @Karasinsky - Although I disagree that whole passage is needed, I would be happy to hear a comment that is entirely off-topic. This is a wonderful site but half bullshit. Why should we be afraid?

Comment: Tut, tut, my good @Zan700. No one who thinks Ophelia is a character in *King Lear* gets to tell this site on this site that this site is half bullshit.

Comment: @deatrat - But elia is half of Cordelia and I didn't exempt  myself from the bullshit. Absolutely a woman. Tragic error.

Comment: @medica - I agree with your point about good writers. It reminds me of a translation of the works of Shakespeare into Yiddish which bore the rather optimistic title "Shakespeare Translated and Improved".

Comment: @Zan700 - true ... I guess in the right context, half bullshit is a half-full glass thing :)

Comment: @karasinsky - That's a very funny title, and your lead into it. I once tried to improve Shakespeare by substituting Ophelia for Cordelia in King Lear. It didn't work out.

Comment: @medica - I'm not looking for anything better than "fail better" for that concept. I'm sure there isn't. Just a verb that conveys that idea. This is from Wikipedia on Beckett: "Knowlson argues that "Beckett was rejecting the Joycean principle that knowing more was a way of creatively understanding the world and controlling it ... In future, his work would focus on poverty, failure, exile and loss – as he put it, on man as a 'non-knower' and as a 'non-can-er.'"[21] Almost like accelerating deterioration.

Comment: And what's a better phrase for accelerating deterioration?

Comment: @medica - Entropy, maybe. In 1969, Artist Robert Smithson created a work called Asphalt Rundown. He chose an ecologically devastated site and then spread hot asphalt over it to accelerate further deterioration. The site died at the artist's hand. The artist said the purpose of his work was to make entropy visible. I think this is similar to what Beckett was up to.

Comment: Nah. Accelerating deterioration may describe the idea of entropy, but it's not a synonym.

Comment: Bless you, Gradgrinds.  What is that I smell? Is it a dead ? . . .

Answer (score 0):

> ... Beckett meant “*[to fail in a way that is even more of a failure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257723/is-there-a-synonym-for-fail-better)*,” and that this was Beckett’s true literary goal. Is there a verb that conveys the second interpretation?

**[WELTSCHMERZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltschmerz)** **:**

> ... a world weariness felt from a perceived mismatch between the ideal image of how the world should be with how it really is.
>
> part of the pain is that the sufferer really wants the world to be otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Beckett, who was close to James Joyce and greatly admired him, could have been looking at the example of *Finnegan's Wake,* Joyce's final work, which was, in most people's and most critic's eyes, a gigantic failure. Many great writers thought he'd gone crazy or was just having a joke at everyone's expense. Which didn't make sense since he spent nineteen years writing it. And when it was finally 'cracked,' begun to be deciphered, Joseph Campbell's *Skeleton Key* being the first book to break it down, it became apparent it was a work of genius, again. So Beckett could have been talking about something like that - you can't fail better unless you try for something harder to achieve than before.

Comment: From what I've read, Beckett thought Joyce had taken writing as far as it could go in terms of complexity, metaphor and allusion. Beckett set off in a different direction.